# No error line number in OpenCV program?

Tags: c++, opencv, c++11

I am a starter for OpenCV. I installed my OpenCV on mac and it succeed. However, whenever I run the program and the program failed, it cannot give which line I am wrong but only output wrong information in OpenCV. For example, I wrote a long program and when running it, it gives the following result but I don't know which line it is(suppose my file is main.cpp)

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (s >= 0) in setSize, 
file /Users/home/Documents/tools/opencv-2.4.9/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 116
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception: 
/Users/home/Documents/tools/opencv-2.4.9/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:116: error: (-215) s >= 0 in    
function setSize
```

so I really don't know where is the problem. I compiled my files using following commands:

```
g++ -Wall -std=c++11 -I/usr/local/include/opencv -lm -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -o main main.cpp
```

So how should I fix the problem? Thanks!

Comment: Apparently , one of your setSize is passing a negative value as parameters. Try using gdb to debug it.

Comment: But is there any way that can indicate which line number goes wrong in main.cpp just as usual program? This will be much easier since my program actually is very big and it would be very difficult to use GDB. Thanks!

Comment: You have to look at the call stack while executing the soft in debug mode.

Comment: @biquette Hey, is there anyway to directly check which line goes wrong?